# Отмена цвета фона при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Например, если наводим на 2ой или 3й блок, то у первого блока цвет становится как у остальных - серый. Если курсор за пределами всех блоков, то у первого блока опять красный цвет

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}

.test:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test active"> blah </div>
<div class="test"> blah </div>
<div class="test testhover"> blah </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

оберните все блоки в обертку `.wrapper`, и добавьте правило  для `.wrapper:hover .active` с нужными цветом

```css
.wrapper { display: inline-block; }
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.wrapper:hover .active { background: #ccc; }

.active {
  background: red;
} 
.test:hover   { 
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test active"> blah </div>
  <div class="test"> blah </div>
  <div class="test"> blah </div>
</div>
```

Comment: один минус, hover на первом элементе не отрабатывает

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев уже пофиксил.

Comment: Отлично) держи плюс